# PHP Apache not Running

Tags: php, apache, freebsd

I am trying to install phpldapadmin. I have installed the code and placed it in my document dir for apache I have also loaded the php5 module into apache config and added the following directory directive.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/www/apache22/data/phpldapadmin/htdocs">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</Directory>
```

However when I navigate the browser to this it just show the php code from index.php any help would be greatly appreciated.

Added this line AddType application/x-httpd-php .php to no effect. Have also restart the server.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line inside `<Directory></Directory>`: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml`
This makes your PHP script execute by PHP interpreter.

(and remember to restart the server. restart the computer if you don't know how to)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache.php

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting the server to make the configuration file changes to effect.